# Is using yowsup library for commercial purpose legal?

Tags: python, whatsapp

I have one query, As I know there is no official API of Whatsapp to send, receive Whatsapp messages or images. But the `Yowsup` library does that all(Thanks to Tarek Galal). So is it legal/legitimate to use this library to use it as web service for commercialize purposes.

Comment: You can read [license](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/blob/master/LICENSE).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the license. it is GPL v3

> You are allowed to sell copies of the modified program commercially,
>   but only under the terms of the GNU GPL. Thus, for instance, you must
>   make the source code available to the users of the program as
>   described in the GPL, and they must be allowed to redistribute and
>   modify it as described in the GPL.

read more at GNU website.

Answer (score 0):

You [can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) but you need to distribute your code along with your program. The GPL works for commercial web services because you do not give your program to the customer. But read the details.